# asp.net mvc razor fill @Html.DropDownList from twotables

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, html-select

with the code bellow i get this :

```
<select id="ClarderSousSecteurID" name="ClarderSousSecteurID">
    <option value="">---  Tous  ---</option>
    <option value="23">23</option>
    <option value="46">46</option>
    <option value="29">29</option>
        ....
</select>
```

What i'm missing to get this :

```
<select id="ClarderSousSecteurID" name="ClarderSousSecteurID">
    <option value="">---  Tous  ---</option>
    <option value="23">Libelle No 1</option>
    <option value="46">Libelle No 2</option>
    <option value="29">Libelle No 3</option>
        ....
</select>
```

View :

```
Sous-secteur Clarder : @Html.DropDownList("ClarderSousSecteurID", "---  Tous  ---")
```

Controler :

```
var data = from p in db.tblUSUAs
                       join f in db.tblClarderSousSecteur
                       on p.ClarderSousSecteurID equals f.ClarderSousSecteurID
                       select new
                       {
                           ClarderSousSecteurID = p.ClarderSousSecteurID,
                           ClarderSousSecteurLibelle = f.ClarderSousSecteurLibelle
                       };
            ViewBag.ClarderSousSecteurID = new SelectList(data.Select(a => a.ClarderSousSecteurID).Distinct().Select(c => new { ClarderSousSecteurID = c, ClarderSousSecteurLibelle = c }), "ClarderSousSecteurID", "ClarderSousSecteurLibelle", ClarderSousSecteurID);
```

Thank you very much.
Nacer T.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the data you are passing to the `SelectList` constructor.

```
 data.Select(a => a.ClarderSousSecteurID)
      .Distinct()
      .Select(c => new { ClarderSousSecteurID = c, ClarderSousSecteurLibelle = c })
```

You are selecting only the `ClarderSousSecteurID` of items in `data`. so the expression `data.Select(a => a.ClarderSousSecteurID)` is going to give you  a collecction of Integers (IQueryable of int) and you are using that result in your later `Select` for both `ClarderSousSecteurID`  and `ClarderSousSecteurLibelle`  value. That is the reason you are getting the `ClarderSousSecteurID` value for both option text and value.

If your join is giving you unique results, you do not need to the Distinct call at all. You can convert your result to a list of SelectListItem

```
var data = (from p in db.tblUSUAs
           join f in db.tblClarderSousSecteur
           on p.ClarderSousSecteurID equals f.ClarderSousSecteurID
           select new SelectListItem
           {
              Value = p.ClarderSousSecteurID.ToString(),
              Text = f.ClarderSousSecteurLibelle
           }).ToList();
ViewBag.ClarderSousSecteurID = new SelectList(data, "Value","Text", ClarderSousSecteurID);
```

But if your LINQ join is giving you records which are not unique and you still want to do a distinct based on  the ClarderSousSecteurID column value,You can do a group by on the `ClarderSousSecteurID` property and convert the result to a collection of SelectListItem.

```
List<SelectListItem> uniqueListById = data.GroupBy(s => s.ClarderSousSecteurID,
                   p => p,
                  (k, v) => new SelectListItem { 
                                    Value = k.ToString(), 
                                    Text = v.FirstOrDefault().ClarderSousSecteurLibelle })
                                                                                 .ToList();
```

And you can use this data for your dropdown as needed.

```
ViewBag.ClarderSousSecteurID = new SelectList(uniqueListById, "Value","Text",
                                                                    ClarderSousSecteurID);
```

Comment: i modified it to this ... but still not wordking : new SelectList(data.Select(a => a.ClarderSousSecteurID, a => a.ClarderSousSecteurLibelle)

Comment: LINQ to entities do not recogize the method System.String ToString()

Comment: I updated the answer with a non group by solution(If you records are unique from your LINQ join). Take a look. Also what is the type of `ClarderSousSecteurID` ? My answer assumes that it is numeric type. If it is of string type, Just remove the `.ToString()` call.

Comment: byte ClarderSousSecteurID  .... is of type byte. so  .... Value = k.ToString(),  is not accepted . I get the error : LINQ to entities do not recogize the method System.String ToString()

Comment: When i change it to : Value = k, .... i get : Cannot implicitly convert type 'byte?' to 'string' .

Comment: You said it is `byte` earlier. Is it `byte` or `byte?` You need to provide accurate information so that people can help your. `ToString()` will work on byte property.

Comment: `ToString()` will work even with `byte?` type as well. I just verified this code and it works fine. So i assume you have some other error or you are not completely following the code i posted in the answer.